# Using a FactoryGirl factory from another factory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory

I have a `:fakeUser` factory defined in `factories/user.rb`, which I use in `user_spec.rb` correctly.

I want to be able to do the same, `create(:fakeUser)`, in another rspec file `potato_spec.rb`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Factories defined in `spec/factories/*.rb` are loaded automatically and should be available in all your specs.

Comment: BTW, you should use snake case, i.e. `fake_user` or simply `user`

Comment: I swear I had tried just outright using it and it did not work. But it does. That's exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature "your potato test" do    
    let!(:fakeUser ) { FactoryGirl.create(:fakeUser ) }

    context "your test context" do

        #...the actions you want to test
    end
end
```

Within the **context** you may have different **scenarios**, for example "when user is logged in" or "when user is guest".
Provided that you have a factory users.rb like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :fakeUser do
      name 'John'
      #... other attributes you might have for the user
    end
end
```

Comment: Accepted because it is correct, however what Stefan commented is exactly what I needed. Thanks.